# Unzipping Zip file = download-corruption guarantee?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, file-corruption, winzip

I downloaded a zip file and was able to successfully extract the contents, using winrar. However the content (bin/cue files) appears to be corrupted. (after mounting or converting to iso, it shows corruption error)

Should I re-download the zip file? Or is the fact that I successfully unzipped it a guarantee that the downloaded file was not corrupted?

Comment: "Should I re-download the zip file?" You managed to extract the zip file, so that indicates the zip file was not corrupt. Downloading again will not help. If the zip file contained corrupted files then corrupted files will be extracted ...

Comment: If you didn't get CRC errors **during extraction** then it is likely that the files had errors in them before they were compressed. 7-zip would come up with errors.7-zip also has an option to "test" the archive

Comment: ZIP uses CRC-32 for every packed file. So it’s likely the download was not corrupted. In fact, it is *much* more likely whatever you did to convert the file went wrong. Please ask about that instead.

Comment: to convert to iso, i just tried a bunch of programs including daemontools. The result was always a corrupt iso file (according to winrar and 7zip). When i tried to mount it, it gave 'corrupt drive'

Comment: Well, I recommend you ask a new question about converting the bin/cue combo to iso. If possible, please provide the cue file.

Comment: Ok I will do that right now

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=20772435735284331764
I can only ask every 40 minutes

Comment: @DanielB https://superuser.com/questions/1291729/corrupt-bin-cue-files-or-are-they